# Varying network delays between two fixed hosts

Tags: networking, routes, router, ethernet

Consider two hosts *A* and *B* on a wired network. Both the hosts send data packets to each other. In a real world scenario, the delays experienced in the direction *A*->*B* can be different from *B*->*A*. One primary reason could different routes in which packets are made to travel. For example, *A*->*B* might take longer time than *B*->*A*, possibly because it travels through a different set of routers or a longer route. Now lets assume that the packets from *A*->*B* and *B*->*A* take the same route for delivery. Can there still be potential causes for different delays between the packets in two directions? If yes, it would be great if someone can elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

They will never be identical. There are lots of factors that will effect the delay. I might not cover all the possible cases, but at-least i will try to recite what i vaguely remember.

1. First of all, they won't take same path. In case other direction takes same path, the counter direction traffic conditions could be different at routers in the core network. The routers could have different queuing policy.
2. The delays depend on the packet size (larger the packet size, larger the one way delay) as the routers treat packets with different sizes differently.
3. Don't forget the time and day. Holidays, working times and rush hours matter.
4. Depends on the measurement layer:- Assuming they have crossed all these things and the packets came to your machine, the time it takes for the packet to reach from the Ethernet card to the transport layer (TCP/UDP) or Application layer  will not be the same for two different machines. It depends on your machine configuration, load on the machine, what OS, kernel etc.,

Practically they can't be same. You can consider them only for approximations and theory.